# Rails - sending invitations to users that already exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an invite method that sends users emails to be part of a team. I have a modal that displays some users that already have an account and a textfield to input more emails and sends an invite for the person to join the platform.
But if I type an email that already exists in the database I get:

> Validation failed: Email has already been taken

But want to send an email even if the person already has an account.

Here's what I have:

```
  def invite
    invite = params.dig(:invite) || {}
    candidate_ids = invite.dig(:candidate_ids) || []
    extra_emails = invite.dig(:extra_emails) || ""
    emails = extra_emails
      .split(/,|;/)
      .map(&:strip)

    new_users = emails.map { |email| team_email_invite(email) }

    candidate_ids.concat new_users.map(&:id)

    invite_data = candidate_ids.map { |uid| {
      :user_id => uid,
      :team_id => @team.id,
    } }

    TeamInvite.create(invite_data)
      .map!(&:email)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to overviews_url, notice: 'Invites sent.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  def team_email_invite(email)
    user = User.new({
      :email => email,
      :password => SecureRandom.hex,
      :role => :shadow,
    })
    user.add_role :recruiter
    user.skip_confirmation_notification!
    user.save!
  end
```

candidate_ids - It's the users that I display on the list(all good)
extra_emails - emails in the textfield

So when I write a user that already has an account in the textfield, team_email_invite tries to create a new user and crashes.

I don't want to do something like

```
begin
  new_users = emails.map { |email| team_email_invite(email) }
rescue
  new_users=[]
end
```

because then it doesn't send the invite.
Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `first_or_initialize`. The block only gets run if the `User` does not already exist. Here's an example...

```
user = User.where(email: email).first_or_initialize do |usr|
  usr.email = email
  usr.password = SecureRandom.hex
  usr.role = :shadow
  usr.skip_confirmation_notification!
end

user.add_role :recruiter
user.save!
```

Comment: Ok that solves half the problem, it only tries to create the user if it doesn't exist. But then, **candidate_ids.concat new_users.map(&:id)** is empty then it crashes without sending any invite.